# How can 2 local Java applications interact?

Tags: java

Having 2 bare console Java applications running on the same machine at the same time I want to have, for example, something like a `friend.println(String s)` im my first app causing the second app to output `s` to its stdout (while there is to be silence in the first app stdout).

How to implement this?

Comment: You'll need this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/ and preferably also http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a message between the two somehow. Since they won't both be running inside the same JVM, you have to use a communication medium that can talk between separate processes on a machine.

You could:

- [Use RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) (tutorials can be found [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html))
- [Use RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html)
- Pipe the output [from one to the other](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/iodirection.html)
- Shared file access: have `app2` monitor a file that `app1` writes to, and react to any new entries in that file
- Use network [sockets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html): Have `app2` make a network socket available to receive communication from `app1` (via connecting to `localhost`)

Which one you choose really depends on what you want to accomplish, and how complex you need it to be. There are pros/cons to each approach. Some of the concurrent/file-based options might produce deadlocks, for example, but any one of those choices should provide a viable method for accomplishing what you describe. The learning curves on these technologies aren't too difficult if there are some you're not familiar with.

Comment: "Since they won't both be running inside the same JVM" - why not? They will be definitely run on the same physical machine under the same user account.

Comment: I'm assuming by "two local java applications" you mean you'll be invoking the JVM twice, once per application, to get them running. I don't mean they won't both use the same **version** of the JVM, on the **same machine**, inside the **same OS**; I just mean they will be running inside of separate `java` processes.

Comment: And I mean "can't I run 2 applications on the same JVM instance?". Really, the only reason why would I need that all is that I actually need 2 separate stdouts.

Comment: Hm, I don't follow the situation you're proposing here. If you are running two "apps" in the same JVM, why not just combine them into a single app? If they were running in the same JVM why would you use input/output streams to communicate instead of method calls? Can you expand your question/example to be more specific about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I don't know how to run many applications on the same JVM (I never knew that was possible). WHy not to merge them into a single application? - Because I need 2 separate stdout streams to output different information to different screens/windows using neither GUI nor web/EE toolkits.

Comment: Theoretically you could, try loading them up and invoking the `main` method in each one, similar to the description here (http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/25564). I've never done it, but maybe it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Establish a connection between two using sockets, pipes, shared memory or something else (maybe JRMI can be used). Design a protocol and/or API for them to communicate, define a println service, and have one app call another.

Comment: +1 for being the only person to mention pipes and shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably Java RMI.

The most powerful would be a custom protocol via TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets or RMI. A Shared-access file that both check periodically. I would suggest either low level sockets or RMI though.

**EDIT**

Adding some links.

From BalusC - [Oracle Sockets Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

And [RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways I can think of:

- Using sockets
- Using a file and appending to that file when a new message arrives
- Java Message Service
- Using a database

Probably of all using a JMS is the best.